# Dynamic json data fields extract into columns in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I want to extract data from json and put into columns.

```
create table mytable (id integer,data jsonb);

insert into mytable (id,data) values(25,'{"_id":25,"indicator 1":"yes","indicator 2":"yes","_validation_status":{"uid":"validation_status_on_hold","color":"#0000ff","by_whom":"super_admin","label":"On Hold","timestamp":1688643788},"start":"2023-07-03T22:03:30.948+05:30"}');
insert into mytable (id,data) values(26,'{"_id":26,"indicator 2":"no","indicator 1":"yes","_validation_status":{"uid":"validation_status_on_hold","color":"#0000ff","by_whom":"super_admin","label":"On Hold","timestamp":1688643788},"start":"2023-07-03T22:03:30.948+05:30"}');
```

**My data is as below**

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 25 | {"_id": 25, "start": "2023-07-03T22:03:30.948+05:30", "indicator 1": "yes", "indicator 2": "yes", "_validation_status": {"uid": "validation_status_on_hold", "color": "#0000ff", "label": "On Hold", "by_whom": "super_admin", "timestamp": 1688643788}} |
| 26 | {"_id": 26, "start": "2023-07-03T22:03:30.948+05:30", "indicator 1": "yes", "indicator 2": "no", "_validation_status": {"uid": "validation_status_on_hold", "color": "#0000ff", "label": "On Hold", "by_whom": "super_admin", "timestamp": 1688643788}} |

**Data is require in this format**

| id | attributtename | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | _id | 25 |
| 25 | start | 2023-07-03T22:03:30.948+05:30 |
| 25 | indicator 1 | yes |
| 25 | indicator 2 | yes |
| 25 | label | On Hold |
| 26 | _id | 26 |
| 26 | start | 2023-07-03T22:03:30.948+05:30 |
| 26 | indicator 1 | yes |
| 26 | indicator 2 | no |
| 26 | label | On Hold |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jsonb_each_text](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html) to extract the key and values from the JSON

```
select id, key, value
from mytable,
jsonb_each_text(mytable.data)
where key != '_validation_status'

id|key        |value                        |
--+-----------+-----------------------------+
25|_id        |25                           |
25|start      |2023-07-03T22:03:30.948+05:30|
25|indicator 1|yes                          |
25|indicator 2|yes                          |
26|_id        |26                           |
26|start      |2023-07-03T22:03:30.948+05:30|
26|indicator 1|yes                          |
26|indicator 2|no                           |
```